# wpf draw shape inside button

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been looking for a solution to this very simple problem for a worrying amount of time, could someone help me out? I'm simply trying to draw an ellipse inside a button.
 This is what I have:

```
<Button Width="48" Height="48" >
    <Button.Content>
        <Ellipse Fill="Blue" />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Comment: Give it a width and a height. I.E. `<Ellipse Fill="Blue" Width="25" Height="25"/>`. I think you can figure out whatever you need from there.

Comment: Alright it works, thank you!